Spark ORC writer generates incorrect ORC meta file statistics(min, max)
We found that Hive cannot concatenate some ORC files generated by Spark 3.2.1 and higher versions which contain long strings.
val valid = spark.sql("SELECT 1 as id, cast(NULL as string) as null, lpad('A', 1024, 'A') as string;") 
val invalid = spark.sql("SELECT 1 as id, cast(NULL as string) as null, lpad('A', 1025, 'A') as string;") 
valid.withColumn("len", length($"string")).show() +---+----+--------------------+----+ | id|null| string| len| +---+----+--------------------+----+ | 1|null|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...|1024| +---+----+--------------------+----+ invalid.withColumn("len", length($"string")).show() +---+----+--------------------+----+ | id|null| string| len| +---+----+--------------------+----+ | 1|null|AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...|1025| +---+----+--------------------+----+

valid.write.format("orc")
.option("path", "s3://bucket/test/test_orc/")
.option("compression", "zlib")
.mode("overwrite")
.save()

When I check statistics of generated files via command hive --orcfiledump s3://bucket/tets/test_orc/ I can see incorrect statistics for the column string
bytesOnDisk: 5    Column 3: count: 1 hasNull: false bytesOnDisk: 23 min: null max: null sum: 1025
Column 3: count: 1 hasNull: false bytesOnDisk: 23 min: null max: null sum: 1025
Processing data file s3://bucket-dev/tets/test_orc/part-00000-ec01de8f-8f6b-4937-b107-e88f5a5d2d67-c000.zlib.orc \[length: 488\]Structure for s3://timmedia-dev/volodymyr/test_orc/part-00000-ec01de8f-8f6b-4937-b107-e88f5a5d2d67-c000.zlib.orcFile Version: 0.12 with FUTURERows: 1Compression: ZLIBCompression size: 262144Type: struct\<id:int,null:string,string:string\>
Stripe Statistics:  Stripe 1:    Column 0: count: 1 hasNull: false    Column 1: count: 1 hasNull: false bytesOnDisk: 6 min: 1 max: 1 sum: 1    Column 2: count: 0 hasNull: true bytesOnDisk: 5    Column 3: count: 1 hasNull: false bytesOnDisk: 23 min: null max: null sum: 1025
File Statistics:  Column 0: count: 1 hasNull: false  Column 1: count: 1 hasNull: false bytesOnDisk: 6 min: 1 max: 1 sum: 1  Column 2: count: 0 hasNull: true bytesOnDisk: 5  Column 3: count: 1 hasNull: false bytesOnDisk: 23 min: null max: null sum: 1025
Stripes:  Stripe: offset: 3 data: 34 rows: 1 tail: 66 index: 108    Stream: column 0 section ROW_INDEX start: 3 length 11    Stream: column 1 section ROW_INDEX start: 14 length 24    Stream: column 2 section ROW_INDEX start: 38 length 19    Stream: column 3 section ROW_INDEX start: 57 length 54    Stream: column 1 section DATA start: 111 length 6    Stream: column 2 section PRESENT start: 117 length 5    Stream: column 2 section DATA start: 122 length 0    Stream: column 2 section LENGTH start: 122 length 0    Stream: column 2 section DICTIONARY_DATA start: 122 length 0    Stream: column 3 section DATA start: 122 length 16    Stream: column 3 section LENGTH start: 138 length 7    Encoding column 0: DIRECT    Encoding column 1: DIRECT_V2    Encoding column 2: DICTIONARY_V2\[0\]    Encoding column 3: DIRECT_V2
File length: 488 bytesPadding length: 0 bytesPadding ratio: 0%
User Metadata:  org.apache.spark.version=3.4.1

For DF with a string smaller than 1024 statistics is OK.
I tried different Spark properties (spark.sql.orc.impl,spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc, etc.)
Am I missing something?
